# Read content of all files inside a directory in order using node.js

Tags: node.js, electron, fs

I need to loop over files in a given directory, and read content of each file. Like this:

```
fs.readdir(dirPath, (err, dir)=>{
    for(var i=0; i<dir.length; i++){
        fileName = dir[i];

        console.log("A: "+fileName);
        fs.lstat(dir+"\"+fileName, function(err, stats) {
            console.log("B: "+fileName);
        });
    }
  })
```

The output is of the above code is:

```
A: B01.txt
A: B02.txt
A: B03.txt
A: B04.txt
A: B05.txt
B: B05.txt
B: B05.txt
B: B05.txt
B: B05.txt
B: B05.txt
```

While I would expect the output to be something like:

```
A: B01.txt
B: B01.txt
A: B02.txt
B: B02.txt
... etc
```

How can I sequentially loop over each file of a directory and read it the proper way?

**Edit**

I updated my code to use statSyn, as follows, as well as adding read file content code:

```
let  content = "";
fs.readdir(dirPath, (err, dir)=>{
    for(var i=0; i<dir.length; i++){
        let fileName = dir[i];
        let filePath=dirPath+"/"+fileName;
        console.log("A: "+fileName);
        stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
        if(stat.isFile()){
            console.log("B: "+fileName);
            fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                console.log("C: "+ fileName);
                mainWindow.webContents.send('getContent' , {msg:data});
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Now I am getting the following result, please note the "C" lines:

```
A: B01.txt
B: B01.txt
A: B02.txt
B: B02.txt
A: B03.txt
B: B03.txt
A: B04.txt
B: B04.txt
A: B05.txt
B: B05.txt
C: B01.txt
C: B05.txt
C: B02.txt
C: B03.txt
C: B04.txt
```

I managed to read all files, but not in order. How can I make sure I read them in order?

**The Fix**

I ended up using `fs.statSync` and `fs.readFileSync` to read files in order. Not to mention using `let` . Thanks to @x-ray and @Skabbi for their help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You getting the output

B: B05.txt

over and over again seems to be a simple scoping issue.

Try using "let fileName".

Comment: I tried let fileName, and it seems to make things better, but I am getting files names not in order (C: B01.txt, C: B05.txt, C: B02.txt, ..), (please check my update above). Is there a way to read each file

Comment: Again seems to be a scoping issue. Make sure to always use either "let" or "const" when declaring variables.

Comment: If the order matters you can try [readfilesync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options)

Comment: I have fixed the code above in the the Edit section. Can you please check what's wrong?

Comment: readfileSync is the fix, can you please update your answer so that other people can benefit from it?

Comment: The reason for "c: <file>" is not in the correct order is because 'fs.readFile' is asynchronous (Recommend you research how async vs sync works).

Comment: I really would not say that using synchronous functions with node is a fix. Async should always be used if possible.

Comment: I need to read files and extract data from them, and process and store data into outpout file. Having ordered data is important here. As for the environment is a desktop app, so using sync is fine I guess :).

Answer (score 1):

`fs.lstat` is an asynchronous function. You can use `fs.lstatSync` instead to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: Can I use callback function with lstatSync?

Comment: No, you can just use its return value directly (`var stats = fs.lstat(dir+"\"+fileName);`). Have a look at the docs: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_lstatsync_path

Comment: I used statSync, but it seems it only gives me the content of first file!